# Setting up Selenium for Java (necessary jars and imports to create a Firefox driver)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, buildpath

I was wondering if someone could share with me what their Build Dependency looks like for Selenium for Java.
I have been trying to create a Firefox driver, but have been encountering this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory: Provider org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.okhttp.OkHttpClient$Factory could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:803)
```

None of the previous stack forums have helped. I tried downloading a few dependencies (i.e. Guava), but still am not able to resolve this error.
Note I am using Java 1.8.0.221, and Eclipse IDE

Comment: Sharing you pom.xml and telling us how you launch your test might help to help you

Comment: I don't think I have one; does my project have to be a Maven file